# Angularjs inconsistent delays between $http.get and $http.post

Tags: angularjs, promise, angularjs-http

Here is a part of the code of one of my controllers.

```
//service call to add record to database
//bookApi has addBook method which contains a $http.post inside

bookApi.addBook(book);

//service call to show list of all books
//bookApi has a getBooks method which contains $http.get call

bookApi.getBooks().then(function(response){
            $scope.booklist = response.data;
    },function(data,status,config,headers) {
        alert('some error occured');
    });
```

What happens is when booklist is displayed in the page sometimes the getBooks call finishes first before the addBook since they are both asynchronous. SO in the page, when a book is submitted in a Add book page, the next page that gets display is the list of books page which sometimes does not contain the newly added book first (you would need to refresh).

How can this be avoided?

Comment: You'd have to chain the get call to the post, otherwise it will treat them both as async in no order. You need to make sure the post finished before doing the get

Comment: `getBooks` should be call after completion of `bookApi.addBook(book)` call using chaining..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chain the promises together in a flat manner like so:

```
bookApi.addBook(book).then(function() {
    return booksApi.getBooks();
}).then(function(response) {
    $scope.booklist = response.data;
}, function(data,status,config,headers) {
    alert('some error occured');
});
```

In order to combat callback hell, return `getBooks` in the callback. Typically, good promise methodology says you shouldn't chain `then` inside another `then`, but return the promise and continue the chain instead.

Comment: The rejection handler in a `.then` method receives an errorResponse object, not a spread of four arguments (data, status,...